# Android - Checkbox how to read value for check state

Tags: javascript, android

I have a checkbox click lister setup as such:

```
pm_check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                HashM hash = new HashM();
                hash.perf(MainActivity.this);

            }
```

How/where can I build in a check which does the following:

- Read the value at a system path (eg. /sys/cpu/cpuvalue)
- If the value is 12 then checkbox should show as "checked" otherwise it should show as "unchecked"

Thank you.

Comment: a) Read the value at a system path?? What do you mean by that?
b) Value is 12. Do you mean if checkbox which text is 12 is selected?

Comment: I want the check statement/code to read a file (eg. /sys/cpu/cpuvalue) and see what the value written in the file is... if it is 12 then the check box state should show as checked otherwise not

Comment: And this file of your `/sys/cpu/cpuvalue` will only have one value? like 12 or anything nothing more in it

Comment: Just one value exists on the file

Answer (score 1):

To read the file you will perform the following code

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String path= sdcard+"/sys/cpu/";
File file = new File(path,"cpuvalue.txt");

//Read text from file
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
    }
    br.close(); 
}
catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Following code to compare your value with check and change it

```
   if(text.equals("12")){
       checkBox.setChecked(true);            
    }
else{
          checkBox.setChecked(false);            
}
```

Comment: Thank you, how would this adapt if the file is not on the sdcard but rather system root?

Comment: Assuming that you have read access status.
Change this line `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader('/sys/cpu/cpuvalue'))`